# On Macs, is there a similar command like "explorer ." in Windows?

Tags: macos, terminal, finder

Is there a way to open the directory I'm currently inside of, within a Terminal window?

On a Windows machine, I know that I can open the current directory in Windows Explorer by using the command :  `explorer .`, and it will then pop open an Explorer window.

Is there a way to do this with a Mac? I want to download an audio file, and put it inside of a directory where I'm making Java code.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, just do `open .`. The `open` command also works for files, opening them in their default app.